# Javascript Replace with Regex Match Not Working

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to truncate some longitude coordinates without any rounding issues. I thought replace() would be the simplest way to do this.

My regex is correct, but I'm apparently not using replace correctly.

Here's my stripped down example. I need to strip all decimal points after the 8th position

```
var truncRegex = /-?\d+?\.\d{8}/;
console.log('-81.82297519999997'.replace(truncRegex, '$1'));
```

What's happening is replace() is stripping the match and leaving me with the remainder prepended with "$1". The result is:
    $1999997

Comment: If you aren't concerned about rounding, you could use `Number("...").toFixed(8)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some answers of RegExp. Alternatively, you could just find the index of the point and retrieve a substring, if you don't care about rounding.

```
var str = '-81.82297519999997';
var truncated = str.substring(0, str.indexOf('.') + 9); // this will give you 8 fractions
console.log(truncated); // "-81.82297519"
```

Comment: This was my fix. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You must add [matching groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) in parentheses to match something that you can refer to with `$1` while replacing. For example:

```
var truncRegex = /(-?\d+?\.\d{8})\d*/;
console.log('-81.82297519999997'.replace(truncRegex, '$1'));
```

`replace()` function replaces everything it matches based on regular expression. Your code simply replaces `-DD.DDDDDDDD` with '$1' string.

You can still use expression you provided, but you will have to use `match`, not `replace`, e.g.:

```
var truncRegex = /-?\d+?\.\d{8}/;
console.log('-81.82297519999997'.match(truncRegex)[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = '81.82297519999997';

// Returns "-81.82297519"
s.replace(/(-?\d+\.\d{8})\d*/, '$1');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(-?\d+?\.\d{8})|.*
```

Try this.Replace by `$1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eZ0yP4/17

```
var re = /(-?\d+?\.\d{8})|.*/mg;
var str = '-81.82297519999997';
var subst = '$1';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```